# How to log webservice calls with Glassfish?

Tags: web-services, logging, glassfish

I would like to know how to configure a Glassfish server for logging the webservice calls ?

I would like especially :
- that the log will contain the adress of the caller,
- and that the log will be written in a file on the disk.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about glassfish, but I've done similar things with axis2 services on tomcat.  In order to create such log files we created custom inflow handlers that used log4j to log requester information.  I doubt that glassfish would have your desired logging built into it, you're probably going to need to implement your own custom logging solution.  What are you using to develop your services?  IE axis2, CXF, etc...

Comment: I prefer not implementing custom logging solution.
I see that Glasshfish permitts to edit several levels of logging. I would like to know which one would be interesting for me (webservice log).